# Connecting Open-Drain inputs or outputs together with one resistor

Tags: interrupts, pullup, reset, open-drain

I had a couple of quick questions.  I am designing a board using 10 IO expanders which I'll use as inputs.  Each has an !INT pin which is open drain and pulled high to 5v through a resistor.  Can I attach all of these pins together to effectively create a 10 input 'AND' of all the interrupt pins to be read by a uC?  Additionally, each of these chips has a !RESET pin that also operate open drain and are pulled high to 5V through a resistor.  Could I effectively reset all of my chips at the same time by connecting them together and pulling the line low?  Finally, I know that I2C operates using open-drain inputs/outputs and you need the pull-up resistors decently close to the actual chips but since my !INT and !RESET lines aren't going to switch at nearly the same frequency, could I get away with a single pull-up resistor for each of the two lines?

The IO Expander I'm using: 
http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/PCA6416A.pdf

I2C Bus Switcher: 
http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tca9548a.pdf

Comment: What's an open drain input?

Comment: And the answer to your question is: yes - that's exactly why they ARE open drain outputs.

Comment: Awesome, now is it OK to use only one resistor for 11 int lines?

Comment: Yes, the resistor is associated with the input, not the open drain outputs.  It's there as a pullup for when none of the outputs are active

Comment: This approach has worked for 50 years, at least.  Not clear why it would suddenly stop working.  Ohm's law hasn't been repealed yet.

Comment: Thank you all! I was almost positive but have heard about the downfall of picking the wrong resistors or not enough resistors in an i2c network.

Comment: i2c is a very different beast. Too high a resistance and the waveform is distorted by the input voltage rising too slowly. Too low and you waste current or overload your open drain outputs.  It's a fine balancing act.  For interrupts you don't really have that kind of problem.

Comment: This technique of connecting several open-connector or open-drain outputs is sometimes called "*wired OR*".

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Open drain outputs act like a switch to ground.  The resistor acts as a pullup for when none of the outputs are active.

If you replace the open drain outputs in your circuit with buttons its easier to visualise:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faIHJx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I think the right most label in the figure should be "output" instead of "input".

Comment: Depends on your point of view.  It's the output of the circuit, but it connects to the input of the MCU.

Comment: Yes it depends. The word "open-drain input" in OP made me think that way. :)